# Which of these two jQuery methods of finding a table row is faster?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I can find table row in the following ways.

Which one is faster? Or is there not much difference?

```js
$('myTable').find('tr')
```

or

```js
$('myTable tr')
```

Comment: No real difference - IMO `$('myTable tr')` is better as it looks the same as CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really personal preference. There is no real advantage from a coding perspective. According to jQuery's [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) docs:

> Selector context is implemented with the .find() method; therefore,
>   $('li.item-ii').find('li') is equivalent to $('li', 'li.item-ii').

**Personal opinion**: Since `$('myTable tr')` is more concise and still very readable, it's my preference.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is just a matter of personal preference.
Technically speaking the `find` method should be faster because the first one is *translated* into the `find` syntax.
I don't think that you should be concerned about which one is faster. You should use the one that suits best for your app. For example, if you want to call more methods on the main object, you should use `find` :

```
$('myTable')
    .aTableMethod()
    .find('tr')
        .aTrMethod()
        .end()
    .someOtherTableMethod();
```

On the other hand, if you only want to select an object's children and you're not going to do anything with the object itself, you should stick to the complex selector :

```
$('parent child');
```

My advice is to choose readability over minor (really minor) optimizations, unless you have strict specifications to do so. This way your code is easier to **understand**, **debug** and **maintain**.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference in the real world, but `find` is slightly faster (in Chrome at least). Here's the results from a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jq-selector-vs-find):

[image]

Note that the test uses `table` instead of `myTable` because I assumed that's what you intended.

Also note that even though it looks like a huge difference in the screenshot above, it's really not significant.

Comment: Chromium 17 and Opera 11.52 give a different results. Firefox 7.0.1 make them square.

Answer (score 0):

`$('myTable tr')` is automatically converted to `$('myTable').find('tr')` behind the scenes, so the latter is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$('myTable tr')` is merely a shortcut for `$('myTable').find('tr')` – so you are better off using `find()` as opposed to the context parameter. By using `find()`, you are eliminating a function call which is always good ;)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to identify nodes is to identify them by **id**, e.g. `$('#myTable')`. Next, your second example will invoke the kQuery parser only once, whereas the first example will invoke it twice - the second is faster.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the simple selectors are the fastest, eg. `#myId`, `.myClass`. This is because they are translated to the native browser functions `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`.

So, finding the parent element first and then using find should be slightly quicker. See [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance) for more info.